# How can i place double click event on ImageView in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I have to place an double click event on Image view..Whenever I double click on Image ,It sshould be Zoom.But I found that there is no such event like double click in Image Veiw.
Can Anyone Tell me How To DO it??
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 12):

Try this approach:

- add `boolean doubleClick = false;`
- and `Handler doubleHandler`
- in onClick check if `doubleClick is true`
- if true, it is a double click
- if not, set `doubleClick` to true and use the handlers `postDelayed` to set it back to false after i.e. 500ms

Answer (score 5):

whenever the onClick() is called the new instance of Handler is created, if the Handler object is instantiated inside onClick().
So, instantiate handler outside onClick().

```
boolean isDoubleClicked=false;

Handler handler=new Handler();
Runnable r=new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    //Actions when Single Clicked
    isDoubleClicked=false;
  }
}

tv.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener){
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view){
    if(isDoubleClicked){
      //Actions when double Clicked
      isDoubleClicked=false;
      //remove callbacks for Handlers
      handler.removeCallbacks(r);
    }else{
      isDoubleClicked=true;
      handler.postDelayed(r,500);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use *long* variable instead handler

```
private var doubleClickLastTime = 0L
view.setOnClickListener {
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - doubleClickLastTime < 300){
            doubleClickLastTime = 0
            doAction()
        }else{
            doubleClickLastTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works best for kotlin based project. Can be used with databinding also..

Comment: One of the cool ways to create double click without a handler or thread. Supports almost all versions.

Answer (score 3):

Maaalte's answer helped me to write this code.

declare doubleClick variable globally

```
   boolean  doubleClick = false;
```

Logic to handle double click

```
 imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        doubleClick = false;
                    }
                };

                if (doubleClick) {

           //your logic for double click action
                    doubleClick = false;

                }else {
                    doubleClick=true;
                    handler.postDelayed(r, 500);
                }

            }


        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `onDoubleTapListener`.

This [link](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-gestures.html) may hep you.