# how to implement double click in android

Tags: android

I am doing a project in which i want to display  a particular message on single  touch and another message on double touch using android.How can i implement it.

My sample code is below

```
if(firstTap){
            thisTime = SystemClock.timeMillis();
            firstTap = false;
        }else{
            prevTime = thisTime;
            thisTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

            //Check that thisTime is greater than prevTime
            //just incase system clock reset to zero
            if(thisTime > prevTime){

                //Check if times are within our max delay
                if((thisTime - prevTime) <= DOUBLE_CLICK_MAX_DELAY){

                    //We have detected a double tap!
                    Toast.makeText(AddLocation.this, "DOUBLE TAP DETECTED!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //PUT YOUR LOGIC HERE!!!!

                }else{
                    //Otherwise Reset firstTap
                    firstTap = true;
                }
            }else{
                firstTap = true;
            }
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: Have you considered using long press as an alternative to double click?

Comment: see this (Implement double click for button in Android)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849115/implement-double-click-for-button-in-android]

Comment: please follow the android usage pattern and use long press. Don't do double click.

Comment: Just want to help, i post an answer [HERE][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595003/how-to-detect-double-taps-on-listview-items-in-android/29564226#29564226

Comment: I post an answer [HERE][1]. Just want to help. :D


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595003/how-to-detect-double-taps-on-listview-items-in-android/29564226#29564226

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why dont you use Long Press event insted while its Recommanded UI. [Read Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217670/question-how-to-implement-android-double-tap) , I strongly recommand to use this.

Or if its anyhow you want to implement you have two options , one is [this using boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191456/how-can-i-place-double-click-event-on-imageview-in-android)
and second is using [Gesture Listener](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/).

Comment: I feel this answer may be dated now. Double clicking is a common interaction on desktop layouts, and while Android isn't a desktop os, ChromeOS is, and now supports Android apps, so whether or not we should be using double-click may vary situation to situation. Long pressing with a mouse is going to be bad UX.

Comment: Another reason to agree with @JediBurrell is for consistency for a given app. We're just porting our Win/iOS/OSX app to Android. Our users are used to double-tapping to take a certain action, and it would be very odd to make Android the only platform where they have to long-press instead.

Answer (score 14):

Try to use `GestureDetector`.

```
public class MyView extends View {

GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // creating new gesture detector
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
}

// skipping measure calculation and drawing

// delegate the event to the gesture detector
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    //Single Tap
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
}


private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    // event when double tap occurs
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        Log.d("Double Tap", "Tapped at: (" + x + "," + y + ")");

        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

It is hold, but,for new readers, I made a small library to simplify this kind of stuff, check this article: [Double click listener on android](https://dev.to/pedromassango/double-click-listener-on-android-f0j).

The library is very small, and here is the [GitHub Repository Link](https://github.com/pedromassango/doubleClick).

And you will just use it like this:

```
Button btn = new Button(this);

btn.setOnClickListener( new DoubleClick(new DoubleClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSingleClick(View view) {

            // Single tap here.
        }

        @Override
        public void onDoubleClick(View view) {

            // Double tap here.
        }
    });
```

Comment: it 100% works thanks

Answer (score 5):

you can use on long click instead of using double click by override this method

```
 abstract boolean onLongClick(View v)
```

Called when a view has been clicked and held.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below modified code::

```
//Check that thisTime is greater than prevTime
//just incase system clock reset to zero
static prevTime = 0;
thisTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
if(prevTime < thisTime) {
    //Check if times are within our max delay
    if((thisTime - prevTime) <= 1000) {  //1 SEC
        //We have detected a double tap!
        Toast.makeText(AddLocation.this, "DOUBLE TAP DETECTED!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        prevTime = thisTime;
        //PUT YOUR LOGIC HERE!!!!
    } else {
        //Otherwise Reset firstTap
        firstTap = true;
    }
} else {
    firstTap = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may employ [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) in that case in Kotlin it shall be like this:

```
yourView.clicks().buffer(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 2).filter {
    it.size >= 2
}.subscribe {
    // Handle double click
}
```

1. We apply `clicks()` extension function on a given view which creates an RX observable sequence.
2. We tell RX to emit an event after either 500 ms or 2 consecutive clicks take place within 500 ms.
3. We tell RX to take only the events only with 2 consecutive click
4. Last but not least we subscribe to the event sequence which is our DoubleClick handler

Answer (score 2):

I did a simple solution like that -

```
buttonTab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int count = 0;
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable = () -> count = 0;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!handler.hasCallbacks(runnable))
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
                if(count==2){
                    /*View is double clicked.Now code here.*/
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Only works in API 29+

Answer (score 1):

I have Implemented the code on which the Background color and text color changes on clicking the screen twice(Double Tap) here is the code...

```
        int i = 0;
        reader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int i = 0;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                i++;
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                };

                if (i == 1) {
                    //Single click
                    handler.postDelayed(r, 250);
                } else if (i == 2) {

                    if(color==1) {

                        reader.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
                        reader.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                        color = 2;
                    }else if(color==2)
                    {
                        reader.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                        reader.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
                        color=1;
                    }
                    i = 0;

                }


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

We have extended the `OnClickListener` so it can be easily applied to any view:

```kotlin
/**
 * Allows to set double click events on views.
 *
 * @param action The action to perform on click.
 * @param interval The maximum interval between two clicks, in milliseconds.
 */
class DoubleClickListener(private val action: (view: View) -> Unit, private val interval: Long = 800) : View.OnClickListener {

    companion object {

        /** The view that was clicked previously. */
        private var myPreviouslyClickedView: WeakReference<View>? = null

        /**
         * Check if the click was a second one or not.
         * @param view The view to check for.
         *
         * @return True if the click was a second one.
         */
        private fun isSecondClick(view: View) =
            myPreviouslyClickedView?.get() == view

    }

    /** Execute the click. */
    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        if (view != null) {

            // Make sure this click is the second one
            if (isSecondClick(view)) {
                myPreviouslyClickedView?.clear()
                action(view)

            } else {

                // Set the previous view to this one but remove it after few moments
                myPreviouslyClickedView = WeakReference(view)
                view.postDelayed({ myPreviouslyClickedView?.clear() }, interval)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The property `myPreviouslyClickedView` ensures that there can be multiple views using the listener.

**Part 2**

Further, we made it a bit easier to assign the listener by extending the `View`:

```kotlin
/**
 * Set a double click listener on a view.
 *
 * @param action The action to perform on a double click.
 */
fun View.setOnDoubleClickListener(action: (view: View) -> Unit) =
    this.setOnClickListener(DoubleClickListener(action))
```

Or, to handle custom intervals between two clicks:

```kotlin
/**
 * Set a double click listener on a view.
 *
 * @param interval The maximum interval between two clicks, in milliseconds.
 * @param action The action to perform on a double click.
 */
fun View.setTimedOnDoubleClickListener(interval: Long, action: (view: View) -> Unit) =
    this.setOnClickListener(DoubleClickListener(action, interval))
```

Answer (score 1):

here is full example double-tap listener in kotlin

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var gDetector : GestureDetectorCompat
    private lateinit var touchListener : View.OnTouchListener

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // instantiate GestureDetectorCompat
        gDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(
                      this,
                      GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()
                    )

        // Create anonymous class extend OnTouchListener and SimpleOnGestureListener
        touchListener = object : View.OnTouchListener, GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            override fun onTouch(view: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

                gDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
                gDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this)

                return true
            }

            override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                Log.i("debug", "onDoubleTap")
                return true
            }
        }

        anyView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener)

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Subclass View.OnClickListener

I have created a DoubleClickListener using an interface and a Thread. It can be used with any View just like classic ClickListener. This is how you can add my listener for double click events.

**Example,**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new DoubleTapListener(this));
```

And in any Activity, Override this method to perform task

```
@Override
public void onDoubleClick(View v) {
    // Do what you like
}
```

### Implementation:

> Let's see the implementation. I have created a simple
>   DoubleTapListener but using this approach you can create complex touch
>   listeners(Tripletouch Listener, single, double, triple listener all in
>   one).

**1) DoubleTapListener**

```
public class DoubleTapListener  implements View.OnClickListener{

      private boolean isRunning= false;
      private int resetInTime =500;
      private int counter=0;

      private DoubleTapCallback listener;

      public DoubleTapListener(Context context)
      {
          listener = (DoubleTapCallback)context;             
      }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

         if(isRunning)
         {
            if(counter==1) //<-- makes sure that the callback is triggered on double click
            listener.onDoubleClick(v);
         }

         counter++;

         if(!isRunning)
         {
            isRunning=true;
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   try {
                      Thread.sleep(resetInTime);
                      isRunning = false;
                      counter=0;
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                }
            }).start();
         }

      }

}
```

**2) DoubleTapCallback**

```
public interface DoubleTapCallback {

     public void onDoubleClick(View v);
}
```

**3) Implement callback in your activity and override the method**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DoubleTapCallback{

      private Button button;       

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            button   = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);    
            button.setOnClickListener(new DoubleTapListener(this));  //<-- Set listener

      }

      @Override
      public void onDoubleClick(View v) {
            // Toast to show double click        
      }
 }
```

## Relevant link:

You can see the full code implementation [HERE](https://github.com/rohitksingh/My_Android_Garage/tree/master/DoubleTapListener)