# Click called 2 times when performed DoubleClick on TextView

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener, double-click

I want to perform different action on Click and DoubleClick event on TextView.

I am trying it with below code :

```
tvcurrentlocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "google map started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        public boolean onDoubleTap(final MotionEvent e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "inside doubletap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("", "Open new activty here");
            return true;
        }
    });


    tvcurrentlocation.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

Please Help!!! 
Regards, 
Sourabh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `Long Press event` rather than `DoubleClick`. Its a stander click event for android device. You can see an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217670/android-how-to-detect-double-tap) on SO.

But if you have decide to use a double click in you app then you can get a help on this [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191456/how-can-i-place-double-click-event-on-imageview-in-android), [Link2](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/)

Comment: yes I have already implimented `Long Press event`.