# Make sub-View Listen for Double-Click in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have the following code in the onCreate method of an Activity:

```
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(this);
gridLayout.setColumnCount(5);
gridLayout.setRowCount(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    gridLayout.addView(imageView, i);
}
setContentView(gridLayout);
```

Now, I'd like for each ImageView in the GridLayout to respond to (listen for) a double-click. How can I go about doing this? (I've already used a long-press on one of the Views to perform a different action so I can't just use this instead, although I realize that would be easier since there's a native listener for it.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i place double click event on ImageView in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191456/how-can-i-place-double-click-event-on-imageview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) Use a boolean with handler (like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5191862/4224337))

- add `boolean doubleClick = false;`
- and `Handler doubleHandler`
- in onClick check if `doubleClick is
  true`
- - if true, it is a double click
- - if not, set `doubleClick` to true and
    use the handlers `postDelayed` to set
    it back to false after i.e. 500ms

2) Use the [GestureListener](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-gesture--mobile-2239) ( `onDoubleTap()` method )

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way, but the first thing that jumps to my mind:

have a boolean flagging a recent click which is set to true when the view is clicked

Create a Runnable outside the onClick method (only ever have the one, don't make one for every click since android limits the amount of threads we can have. Also just good practice.)

```
Runnable doubleClick = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
      recentClick = false;
  }
}
```

then if this was the first click (recentClick is false), use

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(doubleClick, 100);
```

to reset the boolean after 100 milliseconds

of if onClick is triggered and the boolean is set true, you've had a double click.