# Exit content view on double click in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a little problem:
I would like to exit the content view that I can started when I click on an image of the layout.
The code is:

```
final View thumb1View = findViewById(R.id.gorgovivofoto1);
    thumb1View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TouchImageView img = new TouchImageView(view.getContext());
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gorgovivofoto1);
            img.setMaxZoom(4f);
            setContentView(img);

        }
    });
```

This code open a new content view where I can zoom my image, but I want to return back on double click on the image.
Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you use the "back" hw button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some different solutions here

[Android: How to detect double-tap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217670/android-how-to-detect-double-tap),

here

[How can i place double click event on ImageView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191456/how-can-i-place-double-click-event-on-imageview-in-android)

and here

[How can i place double click event on ImageView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191456/how-can-i-place-double-click-event-on-imageview-in-android).

To handle the back button:

You can handle this using: for API level 5

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // your code.
}
```

and for older then API 5 use this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // your code
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I press back button the app exits from the activity instead of remain in. I set a setContentView and when I double click on on the setImageResource I want to return to the previous activity. I partially resolved adding this code after setContentView(img):
`img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(acquaGorgovivoActivity.this, acquaGorgovivoActivity.class));
                    }
                });`

Comment: But with this code I only can return to the previous activity clicking in the background but not on the image.

Comment: If you want to handle the back button, I update my answer.

Comment: Ok, you solved a part of the problem. But now I would like to return back if the contentView(img) is open. How can I resolve this?

Comment: What "return back" means exactly?

Comment: In acquaGorgovivoActivity there are some images, when I click on one of them the code opens a new contentView. If I want to exit from this content view I have to press "back button", but for now when I press back button it returns in Home activity. I would like to know if there is a possibility to execute your code only if `setContentView(img)` is executed.

Comment: I would not substitute the content view of your thumbs viewer. I would use an overlay container where display the image and set its visibility to VISIBLE or GONE.