# Image animate like

Tags: android, instagram

how can i set double tap to like a image in android.(like instagram photos)

I have following code here:

```
    final ImageView photo_show = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgv_photo);// this is main image
    final ImageView imgv_like_photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgv__like_photo);// this is heart image
    imgv_musics_activity_like_photo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    photo_show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            photo_show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    like(imgv_musics_activity_like_photo);
                }
            });
        }
    });

public void like(View view) {
    TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0, view.getWidth(), 0, 0);
    animate.setDuration(500);
    animate.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(animate);
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

And xml :

```
            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgv_photo"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image_photo"
                tools:src="@drawable/no_photo" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgv_like_photo"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image_photo"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_like" />


        </RelativeLayout>
```

this codes just show heart on image when double taps. i want to hide after 2 sec for example.
Can you guys give me a way??

Comment: this link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191456/how-can-i-place-double-click-event-on-imageview-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare global variable:

```
boolean isDoubleTap = false;
Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Within `onClick` you can create a Runnable like:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    photo_show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Runnable doubleTapRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    isDoubleTap = false;
                }
            };
            if (isDoubleTap) {
                //your logic for double click action
                like(imgv_musics_activity_like_photo);
                isDoubleTap = false;
            } else {
                isDoubleTap=true;
                mHandler.postDelayed(doubleTapRunnable, 500); // you can adjust delay in oder to check double tap
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Note: you can also use [OnDoubleTapListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener.html).

Comment: handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

Comment: From comment in above answer, I think you also want to hide after x time. For this you have to create a new runnable and run it after `x` time to hide.  create this in `like` method

Comment: just write the above statement i.e. `Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` below `boolean isDoubleTap = false;`

Comment: edited my answer, I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

For the detection of double tap you should use a `GestureDetector`. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971224/how-to-implement-double-click-in-android), which is a similar case as yours.

About hiding, you can add a second animation with a start delay of two seconds.

Comment: how to set a delay between like_show(imgv_musics_activity_like_photo); and like_hide(imgv_musics_activity_like_photo);

Comment: Use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setStartOffset(long).