# How to add ripple animation for double click and not for single click?

Tags: android, kotlin, ripple-effect

#### Context of the Problem

---

I was currently trying to build a functionality to fast forward videos in ExoPlayer exactly like how Youtube does it. I thought that I could add a double click listener and I was able to do that using the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57182620/17133283).

#### Problem

---

The problem I am facing is that I was getting the ripple animation even when I do a single click which is not what I want. I want to be able to get a ripple only when a double click is triggered. So, for this, I tried to get the number of clicks and then accordingly set the ripple visibility on the view but it did not seem to work for me and instead giving a weird behaviour. The issue can be seen in the gif given below* :

[image]

It can be clearly seen that on single click, it shows ripple. On double click, it shows one ripple right but the other one comes out from nowhere!

#### Code

---

- Kotlin

  ```
        var doubleClickLastTime = 0L
        var clicksDone = 0

        binding.forward.setOnClickListener {
            if((System.currentTimeMillis() - doubleClickLastTimeF) < 350){
                doubleClickLastTime = 0
                clicksDone = 0
                exoPlayer.seekTo(exoPlayer.contentPosition + 10000)
            }else{
                if (clicksDoneF == 0){
                    binding.forward.foreground = null
                }else{
                    binding.forward.foreground = with(TypedValue()) {
                        this@VideoPlayer.theme.resolveAttribute(
                            android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, this, true)
                        ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@VideoPlayerFromUrl, resourceId)
                    }
                }
                clicksDone++
                doubleClickLastTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            }
        }
  ```
- XML

  ```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/forward"
        android:layout_width="550dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginVertical="50dp"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16px"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"/>
  ```

*Sorry for the bad gif quality

Answer (score 0):

If you convert it in kotlin you can use this

```
GestureDetector gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(),new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                // you can put your code here
                return super.onDoubleTap(e);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for you help @Shiv but I have already implemented the code for double click. The problem i am facing is that I was getting ripples for the first click also which i want to prevent.